# create checkbox checking sequence

Tags: c#, loops, checkbox, sequence

Hello I am trying to program some checkboxes to become checked and unchecked in a specific sequence programmatically. I know it sounds dumb, but this is corresponding to some LED controls that I've already coded the check events for.

I want to check a checkbox to start this sequence and uncheck it to stop it. Currently the checking and unchecking of my D2 checkbox occurs fine, but the `do while` loop freezes the form so I can't actually uncheck the cycle box. I probably should not be using `Thread.Sleep` either. Any advice is appreciated.

```
private void cycleCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            do
            {
                D2.Checked = true;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                D2.Checked = false;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);    

            } while (cycleCheckBox.Checked);
        }
```

Comment: Try using a different technique to exit the loop, put a counter in the loop and exit after 10 or something. I believe this is executing in the UI thread so more than likely when you call sleep the UI will sleep making it very difficult to exit the loop. You may have to move the logic in the loop into another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread.Sleep` method will run on the UI thread if called directly in the checked event which is why the UI is freezing. Push the work into a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) (assumption is this is a WinForms app):

> Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals.
>   This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must
>   be used in a window.

Example based on your question:

```
Timer _timer;

private void cycleCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_timer == null )
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        _timer.Tick += DoTimerWork;
    }

    if(cycleCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}

private void DoTimerWork(object obj, EventArgs args) 
{
    D2.Checked = !D2.Checked;
}
```

Comment: yay for timers! i had a hunch this was going to end up the better option. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you but what I would do is drag in a Timer Control at 1000 ms and use a method to figure out which checkbox should currently be checked by using an integer that loops to 0 at a certain point and gets incremented at each tick.